# what is the path start with @

Tags: paths, sockets, netstat

What is the @ character in beginning section of sockets's path in output of "netstat -a" command?

unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10868    1261/X    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0

unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     13901    1537/dbus-daemon    @/tmp/dbus-bzqSWN4VUU

unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     11248    1603/dbus-daemon    @/tmp/dbus-ifHSrM07KF

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that the socket exists in the abstract namespace.  That is to say, there is no socket file in the filesystem named "/tmp/.X11-unix/X0" etc, so they can not be opened using the normal file `open()` system call, but rather can only be opened using the socket `connect()` call.